# How to navigate to another page after executing codes in a function in react-native

Tags: react-native

When I click the Submit button, there is a function named `registerNow()` should be called.In that function, I have to check a condition and based on that condition, i have to navigate to the corresponding page. The following is the button declaration.

```
<Button onPress={() => this.registerNow()} title="Submit"/>
```

and using the following statement to navigate to login page.

```
this.navigateToScreen('Login');
```

When i try to call this function directly from `Onpress{}` button click, it is working perfectly. But not working, while calling from somewhere from other functions.
Here is my dependencies list

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.4",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Update your `react-navigation` package to `"react-navigation": "^2.9.1",`

Answer (score 0):

is registerNow function making an Api Call it will be better if your share your code if your function is making an Api call using Fetch or axios then it is simple by putting .then function after that and place your navigation code under the then()